# Second Countability Preserved under CLOSED Continuous Surjection

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

In my General Topology course we were recently shown the theorem that says that *[Second Countability Preserved under Open Continuous Surjection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Second_Countability_Preserved_under_Open_Continuous_Surjection)* and the natural question is if we can switch the "Open" condition for "Closed":

> **Conjecture**:
>
> Let $T_A=(S_A,\tau_A)$ and $T_B = (S_B,\tau_B)$ be topological spaces. Let $p:T_A \rightarrow T_B$ be a *surjective **closed*** mapping that is also *continuous*. If $T_A$ is *second countable* then $T_B$ is *second countable*

I tried proving it and failed, because being closed is very limiting when I'm trying to apply the function to a basis so the proof for the open case can't be easily adapted :(

then I tried looking it up and nothing showed up and then I found this other [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603726/closed-continuous-surjective-map-with-inverse-images-compact?rq=1) which has a similar question but it adds the extra hypothesis that for every $y \in Y$,  $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact. So now my current guess is that it's probably false without that extra assumption.

Also, I haven't been able to give a counterexample and I couldn't find on in Lynn Steen's *Counterexamples in Topology*

Can anyone hint at me in the direction of a counterexample or proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed false in general. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2196545/4280): if we identify $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$ to a point (so have the equivalence classes $\{\{x\}, x \notin \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ and give the set of classes the quotient topology under the standard quotient function $q$ sending each point to its class), this is a closed map as $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed ($A$ closed, then $q^{-1}[q[A]]$ equals $A$ or $A \cup \mathbb{Z}$, so always closed, making $q[A]$ closed by definition), but the image is not even first countable at the class of $q(0)$, so certainly not second countable.

With continuous $f$ with compact fibres we sometimes get closedness of $f$ "for free", between "nice enough" spaces, not in general though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and consider the quotient space $Y = \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ (that is, all integers identified to a point). The natural quotient mapping $q : \mathbb R \to Y$ is clearly continuous and surjective. It is also fairly straightforward to show that it is closed.

Note that the space $Y$ is not second countable. In fact, the collapsed point, let's call it $\star$, has no countable local basis, so $Y$ is not even first countable. Note that for each neighborhood $U$ of $\star$ there are positive numbers $( \delta_n : n \in \mathbb Z )$ such that $( n - \delta_n , n ) \cup ( n , n + \delta_n ) \subseteq U$ for each $n \in \mathbb Z$. If we had a countable family $\{ U_i : i \in \mathbb Z \}$ of open neighborhoods of $\star$, then for each $i$ we can take these positive numbers $( \delta_{i,n} : n \in \mathbb Z )$ as above. Now consider the set $$V = \{ \star \} \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} \left( ( n - \delta_{n,n}/2 , n ) \cup ( n , n + \delta_{n,n}/2 ) \right).$$ $V$ is clearly an open neighborhood of $\star$, but no $U_i$ can be a subset of $V$, since $i + \delta_{i,i}/2$ is in $U_i$, but not in $V$.